# Using Hibernate SessionFactory with the JPA EntityManager (together)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to upgrade an "old" (but big) spring MVC 4.3.x application to Spring Boot 2.5. Because of this, there is a part of the code that I would not like to rewrite.

This old application uses DAO classes using the hibernate SessionFactory like this:

```
@Repository
public class NationalityDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Nationality> findAll() {
        return CastService.castList(Nationality.class,
                                    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                                    .createCriteria(Nationality.class)
                                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list());
    }
}
```

However, during the migration to Spring boot 2.5 I added a new entity that uses JPA repositories/crud.

**And the problem is that I'm having trouble with transactions. From what I understand it is not possible to have two transactions manager like this:**

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

So my question is how can I configure JPA with spring boot and get the `sessionFactory` in my old DAO classes so I don't have to rewrite all my "old" repositories/DAO?

===========
**EDIT :**

Here is my new config :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.package")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConf {  
    @Bean public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NATIONALITY")
public class Nationality {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "nationality_id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int nationalityId) {
        this.id = nationalityId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

The service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class NationalityService {

    @Autowired
    private NationalityDAO nationalityDAO;

    @Transactional
    public List<Nationality> findAll() {
        return nationalityDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

And the new DAO :

```
@Repository
public class NationalityDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public NationalityDAO() { }

    public NationalityDAO(SessionFactory session) {
        sessionFactory = session;
        if (!session.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } else {
            return this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        }
    }

    public List<Nationality> findAll() {
        return CastService.castList(Nationality.class,
                                    this.getSession()
                                    .createCriteria(Nationality.class)
                                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list());
    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
spring.jpa.properties.jpa.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**EDIT 2 :**

-- REMOVED (characters limit) --

**EDIT 3 :**

-- REMOVED (characters limit) --

**EDIT 4:**

So, I removed all the custom configuration from my last comment (PlatformTransactionManager and EntityManagerFactory) from my ApplicationConfig. I put back the default DAOs and here is the concrete error:

The DAO :

```
@Repository
public class NationalityDAO {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CandidateDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public NationalityDAO() { }

    public NationalityDAO(SessionFactory session) {
        sessionFactory = session;
        if (!session.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public Nationality getById(Integer id) {
        Nationality nationality = null;
        try {
            nationality = (Nationality) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Candidate.class, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return nationality;
    }
}
```

The logger `logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);` give me this error :

```
2021-06-15 10:01:10 ERROR NationalityDAO:154 - No CurrentSessionContext configured!
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:489)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:519)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.getCurrentSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.package.repository.NationalityDAO.getById(NationalityDAO.java:152)
    at com.my.package.repository.NationalityDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c45d52df.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.my.package.repository.NationalityDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3763e5c5.getById(<generated>)
    at com.my.package.service.NationalityService.getById(NationalityService.java:74)
    at com.my.package.service.NationalityService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3b96bdf.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.my.package.service.NationalityService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee4a52fa.getById(<generated>)
    at com.my.package.http.controller.NationalityController.fetchById(NationalityController.java:111)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.my.package.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Ditch that config and use `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to obtain the underlying session. Although I would strongly suggest to simply rewrite to JPA queries (a `SELECT DISTINCT n FROM Nationality n` would suffice or even without the distinct) or JPA criteria API. If you really want to use the `SessionFactory` you can replace it with `EntityManagerFactory` and when needed do `EntityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);`.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, yes of course for the DAO given as an example it doesn't represent many lines. But I have several dozens with complex queries to rewrite... So in the meantime, I am looking for an alternative solution. Btw, I removed all the configuration as advised and removed the following line `exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class}` in my main app, so that autoconfiguration is handled by spring boot.

I have the following error now `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

Comment: You still need to annotate the methods with `@Transactional`.

Comment: With Spring Boot 2.5, just injecting the `SessionFactory` might just work, as the exposed Hibernate `EntityManagerFactory` is in fact the `SessionFactory`, so you might not even need the casts anymore. (Ran into this once when upgrading to a newer version of HIbernate in which they changed the hierarchy of classes in Hibernate).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks again, your help is greatly appreciated, but I'm not sure I understand. I have already annotated with `@Transactional` in my service. I have updated my initial post with the new code if you can check it please.

Comment: Your constructor is wrong, don't call `getCurrentSession` as when the object is being constructed there is no transaction thus no current session. Hence it will blow up at startup.

Comment: I removed it, but it doesn't change anything. This constructor is used outside of spring in an indexing script. I still have the same problem : `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` arg... I'll try to keep digging... thanks

Comment: WIthout knowing where and how this exception occurs this message won't help. Add the full stacktrace as that contains the interesting parts. Also did you configure a `SessionFactory` or do you now only have the autoconfoguration? All in all it feels like you are doing too much at once as well (migrate from spring to spring boot, upgrade hibernate, use JPA instead of plain JPA etc).

Comment: I added the stacktrace. Indeed, this is a lot of things at the same time, I realize it now. I do not have a SessionFactory, only auto configuration.

Comment: The weird thing in your stacktrace is that it fails at the commit, so after the execution of the method. Do you somewhere mess around with the transaction yourself? Like in the `CastService` for instance?

Comment: I have added the "CastService" code in my first post. Btw, I managed to get the code to work by adding a custom `entityManagerFactory` and `PlatformTransactionManager` in my configuration. To make it work I was forced to add this hibernate configuration: `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread`, but I don't know if this is a good practice.

Comment: No it isn't good practice, actually it will make things worse in the long run as you will end up with session and connection leaks. You shouldn't need to add all of that in the first place. What is weird that it fails at commit not on executing the query. So it looks like in your code you are opening/closing transactions yourself instead of letting Spring manage them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added some information to my original post, can you look at "EDIT 4" please? I set it back to default and let Spring take care of everything

Comment: As I mentioned earlier 1 your constructor is wrong you shouldn't do that in your constructor as it will blow up with Spring. The error indicates you have removed this line `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext` from your configuration which is still needed (don't set it to `thread` as that will break things).

Comment: Indeed, but the constructor without parameters is the one used in the Spring context. The constructor you are talking about is never called in Spring, right? It is used in indexing scripts outside spring to give it the session factory.

I don't understand what I need to change, can you be more clear by "is wrong"? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't start a transaction in your constructor. BUt that would just blow up at startup, as stated in my previous comment you need that property (which you probably removed).

Comment: Yes indeed, I added it and now I am back to the start `no transaction is in progress`. I tried to move the Autowired from the SessionFactory in my service and pass it to my DAO, but it doesn't change anything. I removed the condition that does the `beginTransaction`, but still the same :(

Comment: You have a try/catch inside your dao which swallows an exception. Now I wonder if there is another exception being logged and the process continues instead of doing a rollback it will now try to commit as everything went ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need two transaction managers, since hibernate 5.3 the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` can be used to allow for applications to mix JPA access code and native hibernate in the same tx [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

For example take a look at a basic configuration like below

```
    @Bean(name = {"sessionFactory", "entityManagerFactory"})
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Autowired final DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.some.entity");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(factoryBean.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Comment: This approach is interesting, but I'm not sure I understand. Does it mean that I can simply @Autowired my `Session` and it automatically knows what I need (sessionFactory or entityManagerFactory) ?

Comment: `Session` will use the only one existing FactoryBean `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to open the session, the one you defined here and it will natively expose the JPA EntityManagerFactory interface as per the doc linked

Comment: Hi @Nanotron, I have just implemented your solution and it works, thank you. However, my application is slow now during the first hibernate query. It looks like it's the time for the bean to be built?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution at the moment, but I have simplified the constructors of each of my DAOs so that they take a session as a parameter:

```
@Repository
public class NationalityDAO {
    private Session session;

    public NationalityDAO(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public List<Nationality> findAll() {
        return CastService.castList(Nationality.class,
            this.session
            .createCriteria(Nationality.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list());
    }
}
```

And then the magic happens in the corresponding service to retrieve de current session through JPA:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class NationalityService {
    private NationalityDAO nationalityDAO;

    @Autowired
    public NationalityService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        this.nationalityDAO = new NationalityDAO(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class));
    }
}
```

Now its works.